# How to create a async step in spring-batch?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-batch, spring-integration

I have an existing spring-batch `Step` and would like to refactor it with `Async` processor + writer.

```
StepBuilderFactory steps;
steps.get("test").chunk(1000)
        .reader(new FlatFileItemReader<String>())
        .processor(new AsyncItemProcessor<String, String>())
        .writer(new AsyncItemWriter<String>())
        .build();
```

This does not work and complains for the processor:

`The method processor(ItemProcessor<? super Object,? extends Object>) in the type SimpleStepBuilder<Object,Object> is not applicable for the arguments (AsyncItemProcessor<String,String>)`.

How is a step to be build using async?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the output of the processor into `java.util.concurrent.Future` for AsyncItemProcessor.

[API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/integration/async/AsyncItemProcessor.html)